# calling response value inside onCreate (okhttpclient)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, kotlin-coroutines

There is a GET operation above the onCreate code. I want to get the response value of this get operation into onCreate.

My Code

```
fun run() {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build()

            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with [Kotlin coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html). Use can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to work with callback, and [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#lifecyclescope) in `Activity` to launch a coroutine. The code will be something like the following:

```
suspend fun run(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(e) // resume calling coroutine
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            response.use {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

                for ((name, value) in response.headers) {
                    println("$name: $value")
                }

                println(response.body!!.string())
                val qrq = response.body!!.string()
                continuation.resume(qrq) // resume calling coroutine
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And call the method `run` in the coroutine, launched in the `onCreate` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_MainActivity)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val qrq = run()
        // use qrq, for example to update UI
    }

    //another code ......

}
```

Comment: thanks for solutions but i get error

`Unresolved reference: launch`

`Using 'lifecycleScope: Scope' is an error. Use ScopeActivity or ScopeFragment instead`

My Code;
`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val qrq = run()
                // use qrq, for example to update UI
    }`

Comment: Please try to add dependency to app's build.gradle file `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0`

Comment: still error `Using 'lifecycleScope: Scope' is an error. Use ScopeActivity or ScopeFragment instead`

Comment: Ok, if you launch the coroutine like this `lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch { ...`, is i working?

Comment: In this way, the code works, but the application suddenly closes. 

`Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`

`lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch { // does not expect this line to run`

there is if else, it goes to the bottom line without waiting there.